# Is there a way to by default reduce the length of the Windows Explorer search bar (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, address-bar

With the latest Windows 10 update (1909 5/30/2020) the File Explorer search bar has become obnoxiously large. Is there a way to reduce it PERMANANTLY. Everywhere I see they say "uhhh grab the space between to resize" but I am not doing that every time.

[image]

Comment: Just hover over the edge and make it smaller like any window.

Comment: I've observed this behavior as well. I'm guessing that changing scaling settings causes it to resize. I don't use the search function very often at all, but when I open File Explorer the search field is often taking up 2/3rds of the available space.

Comment: As others are noting, normal Explorer behavior is to remeber your sizing choice through restart, shutdonw, etc. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: After dragging the length of search box in file explorer, it will remain the size even after restarting the machine. The VM I tested is in workgroup with Win10 1909.

Comment: @Hicsy - You just downvote the answer, it’s a comment, just ignore it, if the comment really bothers you flag it. I submitted a solution to the author’s problem more than 2 years ago. In all that time, I never received, any feedback whatsoever on the reason it wasn’t helpful. Sounds like you should submit a detailed question with enough details to answer it instead of submitting comments to this question.

Answer (score -1):

> I suspect the actual issue is caused by Microsoft failing to adapt
> Explorer.exe correctly to their own changes (started in Vista,
> completed in W10x1909) where they moved from "DPI" to having
> per-app/per-monitor "scale".

**A terrible work-around until Microsoft fixes the underlying issue:**

1. Open Windows "Display Settings".
2. Under "Scale and Layout" change scale to "100%".
3. Choose another monitor at the top and repeat for each.

On my surfacepro this is a horrible UX, but the need for file-explorer to display full path outweighs the now-unusable-for-touch scale.

*It's possible that you can set all monitors to a more preferable scale eg (125%) so long as they are the same... but only 100% will disable the potential issue for good.*

---

If you must have varied scale: try changing your "Main Display" to the one with the LOWEST scale... And avoid moving the file-explorer off that monitor!

Comment: All my displays are at 4k or greater and at 100% scale. I also have a Surface Pro.

Comment: good to know. thx for the feedback

Answer (score -2):

> With the latest Windows 10 update (1909 5/30/2020) the File Explorer search bar has become obnoxiously large.

Just hover your mouse icon over the leftmost edge of the text field and drag it to the right to make it smaller.

[image]

In my own testing, I changed it once, and it was already applied to any folder I opened.  It's worth pointing out the  size of the field was simply inverently changed on your system.

Comment: That works just fine and I tested it here. Also the size modification stays (again, works for me).

Comment: 'Everywhere I see they say "uhhh grab the space between to resize"'

Comment: @Hicsy - I don’t understand. In my testing 2 years ago and 5 minutes ago, the description I provided, works on Windows 22H2 and earlier. I don’t expect any actual feedback with regards to this answer that can help me improve it